# raw_id_fields for modelforms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a modelform which has one field that is a ForeignKey value to a model which as 40,000 rows. The default modelform tries to create a select box with 40,000 options, which, to say the least is not ideal. Even more so when this modelform is used in a formset factory!

In the admin, this is easiely avoidable by using "`raw_id_fields`", but there doesn't seem to be a modelform equivalent. How can I do this?

Here is my modelform:

```
class OpBaseForm(ModelForm):

    base = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = OpBase
        exclude = ['operation', 'routes']
        extra = 0
        raw_id_fields = ('base', )   #does nothing
```

The first bolded line works by not creating the huge unwieldy selectbox, but when I try to save a fieldset of this form, I get the error: **"OpBase.base" must be a "Base" instance.** In order for the modelform to be saved, 'base' needs to be a Base instance. Apparently, a string representation of a Base primary key isn't enough (at least not automatically). I need some kind of mechanism to change the string that is given my the form, to a Base instance. And this mechanism has to work in a formset. Any ideas? If only `raw_id_fields` would work, this would be easy as cake. But as far as I can tell, it only is available in the admin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change the *widget* for the `base` field, not the field type. I think this would work:

```
class OpBaseForm(ModelForm):
    base = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Base.objects.all(), 
                                  widget=forms.TextInput)

    class Meta:
        model = OpBase
        ... etc...
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the raw_id_field attribute is a ModelAdmin attribute http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields not a ModelForm attribute.

Comment: What's most likely the issue if this comes above the Input : "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." ?

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the entire raw_id_field admin widget, complete with the handy js popup search that the admin page has. You don't even need a model form. Here's how:

```
import string
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget
from django import forms
from models import MyModel

# Have to subclass widget b/c 
# django hardcodes a relative path to Admin Root URL: ../../..
class HardcodedURLForeignKeyRawIdWidget(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget):
    def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
        original_render = super(HardcodedURLForeignKeyRawIdWidget, 
            self).render(*args, **kwargs)
        ADMIN_ROOT_URL = "/admin/"
        return string.replace(original_render,"../../../", ADMIN_ROOT_URL)


class FieldLookupForm(forms.Form):
    my_foreignkey_field = forms.CharField(max_length=10,
        widget=HardcodedURLForeignKeyRawIdWidget(
            MyModel._meta.get_field("foreignkey_field").rel))
```

Add the relevant admin js to your template, and viola

```
{% block header %}
<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In Django 1.4 it looks like ForeignKeyRawIdWidget's constructor changed - using this code as is causes it to throw __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given). If you have imported django.contrib.admin, you can pass admin.site as the missing argument directly to ForeignKeyRawIdWidget and not have to wrap it with the HardcodedUrl version.

Comment: You have to `admin.autodiscover()` to make this work. I'm writing this  into an answer because there's a bit more missing.

Comment: What if you don't want to redirect to admin?

Answer (score 14):

To expand on Voltaire's comment above, the django 1.4 solution is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget
from django import forms

from .models import Post, Photo

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        Photo.objects.all(),
        widget=ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(Post._meta.get_field("photo").rel,admin.site)
    )
```

And the only additional javascript you should need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
```

The important thing here is that you call autodiscover on the admin, otherwise your RawIdWidget won't have a link. Also the ModelChoiceField requires a queryset, which isn't actually used. ModelChoiceField is preferable to CharField because CharField doesn't validate properly (tries to save the id rather than looking up the Photo instance).

**Update**

Django 2.0 deprecated `Field.rel` in favor of `Field.remote_field`.

That `widget=` line will now need to be:

```py
widget=ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(Post._meta.get_field("photo").remote_field, admin.site),
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without redirecting to the admin site?  Ideally something like the jquery auto-complete feature?