# how to use ForeignKeyRawIdWidget

Tags: django, widget, admin

I want to extend ForeignKeyRawIdWidget so I want to be able to use it without setting raw_id_fields.

With the follwoing I don't get an error but I see no effect:

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class GroupProduct(Product):
    ...
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="%(class)s_related")

# forms.py
class GroupProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = GroupProduct
        widgets = {
            'products': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(GroupProduct._meta.get_field('products').rel),
        }
```

This gives me an error: **init**() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

```
products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(GroupProduct._meta.get_field('products').rel))
```

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ManyToManyRawIdWidget instead of ForeignKeyRawIdWidget fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass the related Model-QuerySet to ModelMultipleChoiceField.

```
products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Product.objects, widget=ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(GroupProduct._meta.get_field('products').rel))
```

Comment: The missing objects was a typo.
I had to use ManyToManyRawIdWidget instead of ForeignKeyRawIdWidget

Comment: Commenting to note that Django 2.0 deprecated `Field.rel` in favor of `Field.remote_field`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13917678/98187