# using ForeignKeyRawIdWidget without admin privilege

Tags: django, widget, foreign-keys, lookup

In Django, I have a modelform which has one field that is a ForeignKey value to a model which has 300k rows. A SelectBox does not work on this scale.

the raw_id_fields/ForeignKeyRawIdWidget in admin interface is exactly what I want, and I got it working for my own forms, borrow the example from reference link:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget
from django import forms

from .models import Post, Photo

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        Photo.objects.all(),
        widget=ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(Post._meta.get_field("photo").rel,admin.site)
    )
```

the only problem is the foreignkey look up popup window's url is
    http://mydomain.com/admin/photo/photo/?t=id&pop=1 
So that requires admin privilege to access. 
I would like to allow a normal user to be able to search/fillback foreign keys.
How should I do it, copy/paste some admin app code into my own apps?

my problem is similar to this one, but they didn't mention anything about admin permission issue:
[raw_id_fields for modelforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980405/raw-id-fields-for-modelforms)

thanks in advance!

Comment: I realize this is a fairly old post, but did you ever find a solution? You could post it as and answer and mark it as the accepted answer.