# How to put valid input in a ModelChoiceField widget that inherits TextInput widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-generic-views

This form is updated by a generic view:

models.py:

```
class CustomUser(User):
   user_bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
           return self.username

class SafeTransaction(models.Model):
    trans_recipient = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'trans_Recipient',null = True)
    trans_recipient_email = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, blank=True, null=True)
    trans_sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'safe_Transactions', null = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, blank = True)
    #trans_type = models.CharField(choices=(1,'Buildingwork'))#DROPDOWN BOX
    trans_unread = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    arbitrator_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)
    payment_condition = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount_to_pay = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=50, decimal_places=2)
    is_finalised = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
class SafeTransUpdateView(UpdateView):
'''
    This view lets the user Update a SafeTransaction receipt
'''
form_class = SafeTransactionForm
model = SafeTransaction
template_name = "myInbox/safeTrans_update.html"
```

forms.py :

```
class SafeTransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
''' SafeTranSactionForm '''
#version one of trans recipient
trans_recipient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(), widget=forms.TextInput())

#version two of trans_recipient
#trans_recipient = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))

def clean_trans_recipient(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['trans_recipient']
    try:
        return CustomUser.objects.get(username=data)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        raise forms.ValidationError("No user with this username exists")

class Meta:
    model = SafeTransaction
    fields = [  'trans_recipient',
                'trans_recipient_email',
                'subject',
                'arbitrator_name',
                'payment_condition',
                'amount_to_pay']
```

So in the forms, I'm mainly trying to inherit a TextInput widget from a ChoiceField. Upon actually submiting the form with this version :
`trans_recipient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(), widget=forms.TextInput())` I am told that the choice I typed in is invalid.

As for the second version : `trans_recipient = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))`, upon submitting this form, first an error of :

## invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'inbox'

After which, the item is actually updated!

I have tried a few approaches, but stuck on these two because they seem the most viable. I don't think it would make sense to leave the trans_recipients as the default drop-down field which Django provides for the ForeignKey model attribute, as it would quickly become unweildy with a large userbase.

I would like to know a convenient way to search with a TextInput widget and query my database for the typed term, and in this case update an Item with the generic UpdateView class.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9491526/5312750)?

Comment: Getting an error :  'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'rel'